# reducing array elements using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, javascript-objects

I am getting an array of data containing many parameters. For example, the data array is in the below format:

```
var data  = [
             {
               "name":"pradeep", 
               "age": "32", 
               "location": "Bangalore"
             }, 
             {
               "name":"praveen", 
               "age": "30", 
               "location": "Mangalore"
             }, 
             {
               "name":"Ajay", 
               "age": "32", 
               "location": "Hubli"
             }
           ]
```

I want the above array to be reduced to the below format:

```
     [
             {
               "name":"pradeep"
             }, 
             {
               "name":"praveen"
             }, 
             {
               "name":"Ajay"
             }
           ]
```

How to get this done using Underscore. I tried using the _.pluck but it fetches only the data and not the key.

Comment: Check out the _.pick or _.omit functions. They are functions that filter objects.

Comment: @DenisFrezzato I wrote an answer recommending `_.pick`, then I realised the OP wants an array of objects and `pick` only works on single objects.

Comment: It can be achieved using _.map to loop through the array and _.pick to filter the object.

Comment: @DenisFrezzato indeed, but it's hardly efficient.  `_.pick()` is best suited for when there are multiple keys to be copied, and/or when the keyname is variable.

Comment: I agree with you, but @Pradeep has specified Underscore...

Answer (score 1):

You could use pure JavaScript to do it, one way is:

```
data.map(function(obj) { 
    return {'name': obj.name};
})
```

If you'd like to parametrize key that should be kept, you may write function like that:

```
function filterByKey(arr, key) {
    return arr.map(function(obj) {
        var newObj = {};
        newObj[key] = obj[key];
        return newObj;
    });
}
```

and use it like that:

```
var newData = filterByKey(data, 'name');
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For a strictly underscore JS method you can use `_.map` combined with `_.pick`:

```
var newData = _.map(data, function(d) { return _.pick(d, 'name' })
```

However using `_.pick` will not be as efficient as just simply returning `{ name: d.name }` in the `_.map` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Underscore is not really required, you can do this..

```
var newData = data.map(function (x) {
    return { name: x.name };
});
```

but if you really want to use underscore this is the way:

```
var newData = _.map(data, function (x) {
    return { name: x.name };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In native JavaScript, you can do it like:

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "pradeep",
  "age": "32",
  "location": "Bangalore"
}, {
  "name": "praveen",
  "age": "30",
  "location": "Mangalore"
}, {
  "name": "Ajay",
  "age": "32",
  "location": "Hubli"
}];

var newData = data.map(function(d) {
  return { name: d.name }
});

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [map](http://underscorejs.org/#map) function from Undescore. It's a very popular utility from the functional programming and you can also use it natively in the browser.

With Underscore.js the code looks like this:

```
_.map(data, function(element) {
  return {name: element['name']};
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using native JavaScript

```
var result = [];
data.forEach(function(d){
 result.push({'name': d.name}) // d is an iterator
})
```

You could as use map function to return the key value pair

```
var result = data.map(function(d){
 return {'name': d.name}
})
```